# How can I get the list of Users who have updated/made the changes the Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, macros, excel-2007, vba

I am sharing an Excel 2007 Multi user Workbook and ask my team to update it. To find the defaulters, how can I get the list of Users updated the Excel sheet ??

Comment: Could you just ask your team who updated it?  You can do some fancy stuff with VBA to track changes, and the users who did such changes, but that's going to be way more complicated and error prone than asking your team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in "Track Changes" feature provided by Excel. You can find tutorial on its use here:

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/track-changes-and-comments/1/

Comment: Do we have this feature in MS Excel 2007 ??

Comment: Yes, I believe this is a long running feature in MS Office. It is under the "Review" tab of buttons.